# Search vector in Matriz Java

Tags: java, vector

I am Spanish excuse me my bad english level.

I have a project, and two classes "PosicionMatriz.java"

```
public class PosicionMatriz{
private int x;
private int y;

public PosicionMatriz(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int dameFila(){
    return x;
}

public int dameColumna(){
    return y;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return ("["+dameFila()+"]["+dameColumna()+"]");
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof PosicionMatriz){
        PosicionMatriz pm = (PosicionMatriz) obj;
        if (x == pm.x && y == pm.y){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

and other class "buscaVectorEnMatriz.java"
The project consists in search a vector in a matriz, for example.

So, the program have find the vector in matriz by files, how I can resolve this problem, I don't want the solution only a track.Example:

```
int[][] m = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{1,2,5,6,7,8},{1,2,3,7,8},{1,6,7,8}};
int[]   v = {3,7,8};
PosicionMatriz res = buscaVectorEnMatriz(m,v);
    if(res == null){
       System.out.println("Vector no encontrado");
    }else{
       System.out.println("El vector se ha encontrado en la posición " + res);
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is exactly the problem / your question? How to implement the method `buscaVectorEnMatriz`?

Comment: Yes, I know search an element in vector or matriz, but I don't know search a vector.